# Is there any way to put HTML in the label of this jQuery seating plan plugin?

Tags: jquery, html

I am playing around with [this jquery seating chart plugin](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts). you can set a label in a set in either the map like this:

```
   map: [
        'aa[,This is the label for this entry]aaaaaaaaaa',
        'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
```

or the  "getlabel()" function like this:

```
 getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
    return character + " is my label";
 }
```

but I wanted to see if there is any ability to return html as the label as opposed to just raw text?  (I tried sticking in some html table in either approach above and neither seems to work.

Looking at the comments in the plugin I see this:

```
  * Allowed characters in labels are: 0-9, a-z, A-Z, _, ' ' (space)
```

but it seems like an obvious basic thing someone would want to do is put html into this label as all its doing it shoving it into a div.

Comment: post your own jsfiddle so we can update , modify it

Comment: Hi @leora may I know how to implement this script in mysql db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your copy of jQuery-Seat-Charts 1.1.0 (either the full or the minified version),

1. find `.text(fn.settings.label)`
2. replace with `.html(fn.settings.label)`

HTML returned from function `naming.getLabel` will then be honoured.